# Skipping without having errors if an item doesn't exist in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am iterating arrays within arrays what I have. Some inner arrays does not have certain attribute called "validations" and some does. Whenever my loop hits an array with no certain attribute, it throws an error saying "no validations" and stop looping.

I'm calling this function:

```
$scope.groups[a].sections[0].fields[1]["validations"]
```

I wonder if there's a way to skip current array if the array does not have validations.

Thanks

Comment: Use [try catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a property is not defined, it evaluates to `undefined` when addressed. As a boolean, `undefined` evaluates to `false`.

```
if ($scope.groups[a].sections[0].fields[1]["validations"]) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Trying to use your block of code results in a `ReferenceError: $scope is not defined`

Comment: yeah so how do I ignore the error and keep moving on in the loop?

Comment: @Kahsn add the code with "the loop" to your question - so that I can understand what loop you are talking about

Comment: @Igor `if ($scope.groups[a].sections[0].fields[1].['valadations']) { console.log('All these fields exist!') } console.log('No error will stop me!')` will log no text.

Comment: @Igor It looks like we're thinking about this differently. I thought the question was about any of the attributes on the way down being undefined. In F#, you can do something like `foo?baz?bar` and if of those is null on the way down, it returns null. Now I see you're just dealing with valuations not existing.